# Multivariable differentiation limit proof

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Im trying to prove that for any a,b,c, $\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow 0} \frac{a x^{2}+b x y+c y^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=0$. Clearly, I see that this makes sense intuitively but I'm unsure how to go about formally proving it. I was wondering if anyone could help lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

I would start with noticing that
\begin{align*}
0\leq |x| = \sqrt{x^{2}} \leq \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} \Rightarrow 0\leq \left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}\right| \leq 1
\end{align*}

Similarly, we also have that
\begin{align*}
0\leq |y| = \sqrt{y^{2}} \leq \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} \Rightarrow 0\leq \left|\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right| \leq 1
\end{align*}

Consequently, we deduce according to the triangle inequality and the previous results that:
\begin{align*}
0\leq \left|\frac{ax^{2} + bxy + cy^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}\right| \leq |ax| + |bx| + |cy|
\end{align*}

Then apply the squeeze theorem.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Comment: @mathenthusiast you are welcome ! I am glad I could help.